# Will the Traveling Salesman Problem (TSP) become easier if the simple path constraint is omitted?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, time-complexity, np-complete

Will the Traveling Salesman Problem (TSP) become easier if the simple path constraint is omitted?
That is, each node in the topological graph should be visited once **at least** (instead of **exactly**).

Is it still NP-complete or reduced to a P problem?
How would this modification affect classical methods for solving the original TSP such as dynamic programming, mixed integer programming, meta-heuristics and maybe branch-and-cut/bound/price?

---

What I have tried:

I believe this variant might be easier to solve, but after a sketchy thought about the MIP model, I found it is hard to write the sub-tour elimination constraints.

I have checked [TSP Where Vertices Can be Visited Multiple Times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39833023/tsp-where-vertices-can-be-visited-multiple-times) but it is asking for a working solution which could be a heuristic that does not guarantee the optimality and computational time. This is not what I want.

Answer (score 9):

No, it doesn't become easier. Metric TSP (the version where the distances obey the triangle inequality) is still **NP**-complete but, in this scenario, the shortest tour always visits every city exactly once. The triangle inequality guarantees that going directly to a new city is always faster than going there via somewhere you've already been.

Comment: Also, with arbitrary distance TSP you could replace each distance from A to B with the shortest path from A to B in polynomial time, so solving "Metric TSP" solves "TSP without single path constraint" completely.

Comment: @gnasher729 if "TSP without single path constraint" (A) can be reduced to "Metric TSP" (B), we can infer that B is harder than A only. e.g. "deciphering codes with the key" (A) can be reduced to "deciphering without the key" (B) by just forgetting the key, it is clear that B is harder than A and solving A is pretty easy.